# cocoapods: An unexpected version directory was encountered. How do I fix this?

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods, iqkeyboardmanager

I am running CocoaPods to add a dependency to my project.

My pod file is located at Users/myUser/Desktop/project/project.

It looks like this:

```
source 'https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager.git'

pod 'IQKeyboardManager'

xcodeproj '../project.xcodeproj'
```

and it is named Podfile.

When I run `pod install`, I get this output:

> Analyzing dependencies
>
> [!] An unexpected version directory `Categories` was encountered for the `/Users/myUser/.cocoapods/repos/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager` Pod in the `IQKeyboardManager` repository.

What is CocoaPods expecting here and how can I fix this?

Thanks,

C

Answer (score 1):

How to fix this is described in the Cocoapod repo, [issue 6089](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/6089).

Jest of it copied here in case link breaks in the future:

1. Starting point

I try to create a private pod.

- Environment:
  Xcode 8
  Cocoapods 1.1.1
- My Pods file tree:

looks like this

```
.
├── LICENSE
├── MoudlePod3
│   ├── 0.0.1
│   │   └── MoudlePod3.podspec
│   ├── TestObject3.h
│   └── TestObject3.m
├── MoudlePod3.podspec
└── README.md
```

- run pod install

Everything is perfect!

- Change creating the issue:
  Then I add some new folder and files to the pod
  Updated pods file tree:

`.
 ├── LICENSE
 ├── MoudlePod3
 │   ├── 0.0.1
 │   │   └── MoudlePod3.podspec
 │   ├── 0.0.4
 │   │   └── MoudlePod3.podspec
 │   ├── NewClass
 │   │   ├── TestObjectNew.h
 │   │   └── TestObjectNew.m
 │   ├── TestObject3.h
 │   └── TestObject3.m
 ├── MoudlePod3.podspec
     └── README.md`

- Increment podspec version to 0.0.4
- Update client's podfile as follow:
  Demo Project Pod file:

  source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
  source 'http:///ljb/MoudlePod3.git'

  target 'MoudleApp' do
  pod 'MoudlePod3', '~> 0.0.4'
  end
- run pod install

[!] An unexpected version directory NewClass was encountered for the /Users/apple/.cocoapods/repos/MoudlePod3/MoudlePod3 Pod in the MoudlePod3 repository.

3. Explanation & solution from @benasher44 :
   Ah, so source 'http:///ljb/MoudlePod3.git' means that it expects that to be a specs repo, but **it looks like you're trying to combine a specs repo and the repo where you keep the code for your pod, which is unsupported**. 
   You should instead remove the custom source line and do something like pod 'MoudlePod3', '~> 0.0.4', :git => ''. Checkout https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/the-podfile.html#from-a-podspec-in-the-root-of-a-library-repo for more info.

or in my case fix the source line to point to the private specs repo not the pod's source repo... Doh!

Hope that helps.

Comment: 3rd point helped me. Thanks

Answer (score -2):

I had a similar issue:

```
[!] An unexpected version directory `Base.lproj` was encountered for the etc...
```

updating to the latest version of cocoapods seemed to resolve it:

```
gem install cocoapods --pre
```

Have a look at [CocoaPods issue](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/2923)

Hope that helps.

Comment: thanks, in my case updating source to'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git' fixed it

Comment: In my case, even updating to github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git still yields a similar error

Comment: this issue is about version 0.35.0 :(

Comment: I'm on Cocoapods 1.2.1, ruby 2.0.0p481, RubyGems 2.4.5, Mac OS X 10.12.5, Xcode 8.3.3 and still experiencing this issue. 
Surely it's been fixed since cocoapods 0.35.0? Anyone knows how to solve this?